# access kibana with traefik ingress

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I would like to configure access to kibana with ingress.

I'm using Traefik reverse proxy.

I have this configuration, and can't get it to work.

What is the right configuration to make it work?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: rule-001
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    #traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/app/kibana#/"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    #ingress.kubernetes.io/referrer-policy: /
    #traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-modifier: "AddPrefix: /app/kibana"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip
    #traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathStrip
    #traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefix
    #traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: Path
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: "/"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-host: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kibana-logging
          servicePort: 5601
        path: /kibana
        #path: /app/kibana
```

Here the are the access via nodeport logs (works):

```
{
   "type":"response",
   "@timestamp":"2020-06-04T11:12:26Z",
   "tags":[

   ],
   "pid":6,
   "method":"get",
   "statusCode":200,
   "req":{
      "url":"/ui/fonts/inter_ui/Inter-UI-Bold.woff2",
      "method":"get",
      "headers":{
         "host":"3.221.49.216:30346",
         "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0",
         "accept":"application/font-woff2;q=1.0,application/font-woff;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
         "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.5",
         "accept-encoding":"identity",
         "dnt":"1",
         "connection":"keep-alive",
         "referer":"http://3.221.49.216:30346/app/kibana"
      },
      "remoteAddress":"172.31.55.73",
      "userAgent":"172.31.55.73",
      "referer":"http://3.221.49.216:30346/app/kibana"
   },
   "res":{
      "statusCode":200,
      "responseTime":240,
      "contentLength":9
   },
   "message":"GET /ui/fonts/inter_ui/Inter-UI-Bold.woff2 200 240ms - 9.0B"
}
```

Here are the access  via ingress logs (wont work):

```
{
   "type":"response",
   "@timestamp":"2020-06-04T11:15:29Z",
   "tags":[

   ],
   "pid":6,
   "method":"get",
   "statusCode":200,
   "req":{
      "url":"/app/kibana",
      "method":"get",
      "headers":{
         "host":"3.221.49.216",
         "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125",
         "accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
         "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
         "accept-language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
         "cache-control":"max-age=0",
         "upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
         "x-forwarded-for":"148.71.30.119",
         "x-forwarded-host":"3.221.49.216",
         "x-forwarded-port":"80",
         "x-forwarded-prefix":"/kibana",
         "x-forwarded-proto":"http",
         "x-forwarded-server":"node1",
         "x-real-ip":"148.71.30.119"
      },
      "remoteAddress":"172.31.55.73",
      "userAgent":"172.31.55.73"
   },
   "res":{
      "statusCode":200,
      "responseTime":10,
      "contentLength":9
   },
   "message":"GET /app/kibana 200 10ms - 9.0B"
}
```

Using host configuration in ingress works, but I would like to use the path.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: rule-001
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kibana.host.com 
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kibana-logging
          servicePort: 5601
        path: /
```

Comment: Both should work , but in path based routing you need "/app/kibana" instead of just "/kibana"

Comment: i did try it before, try it again with /app/kibana, and dont work, only works the with host: kibana.host.com :(